# Displaying a multivalue SSRS parameter in the report title

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008

I have a text multivalue parameter in SSRS 2008 which I want to use in the report title.

If I just drag it into the title, when the report runs it says #Error.

What kind of expression do I need to write to get the values as a comma seperated string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The multivalue parameter is an array, to display a comma separated list you need to do something like this:

```
=Join(Parameters!MultiValueParam.Value, ",")
```

Comment: In the end, used a tiny modification: =Join(Parameters!MultiValueParam.Label, ",")